# What happens when only the verb is left after a subordinate clause?

Tags: usage, word-order, relative-clause

Simple example:

> A1) Der Mann, den wir gestern sahen, rennt.

Is that correct with that lone verb at the end or should it better be

> A2) Der Mann rennt, den wir gestern sahen.

another example

> B1) Ich werde alle Zeitungen, die du willst, bringen.

vs.

> B2) Ich werde alle Zeitungen bringen, die du willst.

I hope you get the idea of what I mean.

Edit: to clarify, the two examples are meant to be the german translation of

> The man we saw yesterday is running

and

> I will bring all the newspapers (that) you want

Comment: you first example part 2 is faulty

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: alright. you finish your sentence: *Der Mann rennt*. and then you requalify the subject? in a relative clause?  noone does that. i don't even know if this is gramatically allowed, but the order of sentence does not make sense in this example. on the other hand the second example part two is correct, because you requalify something else. not *ich* but *alle*.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at (though probably you meant "not er but alle"). So I take that when you say something about the subject in a subordinate, form 1 from my first example should be used?

Comment: yup. basically that's what i'm saying. by the way. in your second example *ich* is the subject and thus the equivalent to *er* in the first ;) that's why "not ich but alle"

Comment: Ah, I see now. So instead, in the second example scenario, are both forms acceptable? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7738

Comment: @Vogel612: I disagree; in my opinion, A2 is unusual, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: @chirlu can you prove it? Because I do not know, but strongly suppose it is grammatically not correct

Comment: @Vogel612: I am a native speaker, it is already proof that I find it acceptable. :-)

Comment: @chirlu well that's a tie then... 'cause I am a native speaker too. and to prove it, you would need a bit more than that :(

Comment: @Vogel612: Let's have a look into _Duden_ grammar to break the tie. :) (4th ed., 1984; _Rz._ 1284.) _[Der Teilsatz] folgt dann seinem Bezugswort. Steht dieses im Vorfeld, dann steht der Attributsatz im Vor- oder Nachfeld; [...]: Der Mann, der dies getan hat, ist bekannt. Der Mann ist bekannt, der dies getan hat. [...]_

Comment: So ISTU that A2 would be correct, even if a bit strange?

Comment: damn. seems like it. i was prepared to bet it was not allowed... well always learn something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for B1 and B2, I'd like to note that both are possible, but have different connotations:

> B1) Ich werde alle Zeitungen, die du willst, bringen.

This would be used as a reply if you get a list of newspapers being supposed to buy them. The translation I'd choose would be *I'll bring you **all the** papers you want*.

> B2) Ich werde alle Zeitungen bringen, die du willst.

This in German has to connotation of *I'd do anything for you*. Example: Your wife has the flu and asks you to go and buy her the `Times`. Then you could use the above sentence, which I'd translate as *I'll bring you **any** paper you want*.

Answer (score 8):

In German, using subordinate clauses and sticking the verb at the end is how you build these arbitrarily long, nested sentences.

> Der Mann, den wir gestern, als ich alle Zeitungen, die du wolltest, brachte, sahen, rennt.

I personally find the version with the verb at the end more pleasing to the ear. Provided the nesting level doesn't exceed one, that is. More than that (particularly if you don't see the sentence written down), and you're fast heading into mental stack overflow territory.

> Der Mann rennt, den wir gestern sahen.

I don't know if that's grammatically correct or not, but the two clauses aren't well connected and full sentence sound disjoint and generally awkward.

Comment: The last example sounds a bit strange. When talking to another I'd rather use *Da rennt der Mann, denn wir gestern sahen.*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's why I'm not sure if that sentence is grammatically correct. If it doesn't sound right, it probably isn't...